# How can I stop using https on Webmail in Webmin

Tags: ssl, webmin

I have a virtual server and it doesn't have an ssl certificate. When I try to use webmail from http://webmail.oznurdavetiye.com, I encounter "your connection is not secure message" because of https redirection.

If I edit directives as "RewriteRule ^(.*) http://oznurdavetiye.com:20000/ [R]", I encounter "Error - Document follows, This web server is running in SSL mode ".

How can I configure a virtual server's webmail to work without an https connection ?

Answer (score 0):

It's done in ***Webmin->Usermin Configuration->SSL Encryption***.

You need to either disable *Enable SSL* or *Redirect non-SSL requests to SSL mode* options.

Afterwards, you will not be redirected to SSL version and thus will not see the certificate error.

The other possible solution is to get free SSL certificate for your domain, for example from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).